# Grouping by a column and finding the most recent anomalies in another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, group-by

I have a dataset where an `id` can receive various `product_codes` over time. Time or the `date` column goes back to almost 10 years ago. I need to identify if an `ID` has received (a) different `product_code(s)` in the last month of its `product_codes` compared to all its historical `product_codes`.

A snapshot of my data is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
           product_code=c("178","321","252","147","178","321","252","147","178","322","253","698",
                  "411","322","253","670"),
           date=c("2022-10-10","2022-10-10","2022-10-10","2022-10-10","2022-11-10","2022-11-10","2022-11-10",
                 "2022-11-10","2022-12-10","2022-12-10","2022-12-10","2022-12-10","2023-02-10",
                 "2023-02-10","2023-02-10","2023-02-10") )
```

We can look at the `IDs` as shown below:

```
df %>% arrange(id)
   id code       date
1   1  178 2022-10-10
2   1  178 2022-11-10
3   1  178 2022-12-10
4   1  411 2023-02-10
5   2  321 2022-10-10
6   2  321 2022-11-10
7   2  322 2022-12-10
8   2  322 2023-02-10
9   3  252 2022-10-10
10  3  252 2022-11-10
11  3  253 2022-12-10
12  3  253 2023-02-10
13  4  147 2022-10-10
14  4  147 2022-11-10
15  4  698 2022-12-10
16  4  670 2023-02-10
```

The outcome of interest is like

```
id         new_product_code
1              1
2              0
3              0
4              1
```

I am using this code but it is not working

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_product_code=if_else(any(product_code[date>max(date)-30]) %in%
                                    product_code[date<max(date)-30],1,0)) %>% 
  select(id,new_product_code)
```

I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks! No, it's only ```1``` and ```4``` that have different ```code``` compared to their previous ```codes```. I made the data more clear and hope it helps.

Comment: My fault. by recent I meant over the past month. So, the ```2``` is good in this case and I modified the question, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant the max date of each ```id``` - ```30 days```, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, here is one solution. You can first create a function that for any given id, pulls the list of all previous product codes, excluding the latest one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
getting_previous_codes <- function(new_id) {
  df %>% 
    filter(id == new_id) %>% 
    filter(date <= as_date(max(date)) - months(1)) %>% 
    pull(product_code)
}
```

Then you can filter to get the latest codes, and using the previous function we check if the current code appears in the list of previous codes.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(date >= as_date(max(date)) - months(1)) %>% 
  mutate(
    new_product_code = 
      if_else(product_code %in% getting_previous_codes(new_id = id), 0, 1)
  ) %>% 
  summarize(
    new_product_code = if_else(sum(new_product_code) > 0, 1, 0)
  )
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I need to look into the last month for each ID and not only the max date. so I modified your code into ```filter(date < max(date)-30)``` in both chunks but I am getting an error. Can you please edit it in a way that works for me?

Comment: @Alex do you want it to be max date minus one month or current month minus one month?

Comment: max date of each ```id```  minus one month. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Alex adjusted the code to account for what you said

Answer (score 0):

Here, I identify if a user's product_id differs from the prior one, and just keep the last observation per user.

```
library(dplyr) #relies on v1.1.0+ for the `.by` / `by` parameters.
df %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  mutate(new_prod = as.numeric(product_code != lag(product_code, default = ""), .by = id)) %>%
  slice_max(date, by = id)

  id product_code       date new_prod
1  1          411 2023-02-10        1
2  2          322 2023-02-10        0
3  3          253 2023-02-10        0
4  4          670 2023-02-10        1
```

Comment: Thanks! can you modify it in a way that it identifies if any of the ```product_codes``` of the last month of each ID is different form any of the ones prior to a month ago of each ID?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an example of input and output that demonstrates that? It's unclear to me. If a user had two product codes month 1 and two product codes month 2, is that two codes in month two that are each different from any of the ones a month ago? And your question says to "compare to all its historical product_codes", but here you refer to "ones prior to a month ago"?

Comment: thank you for helping. By historical, I meant everything prior to a month ago. So, all ``` product_codes``` withing the last month of each ```ID``` compared to the remaining ones.

Comment: ```df %>% group_by(id) %>% utate(new_product_code=if_else(any(product_code[date>max(date)-30]) %in%                                product_code[date<max(date)-30],1,0))``` basically, this is the logic that I need to develop.